# SQL Server WHERE NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the 3 below statements,

1. Selects the Order Numbers that dont exist

> ```
> select Orders.OrderNumber 
> FROM Orders 
> inner join InvoiceControl on Orders.OrderNumber = InvoiceControl.OrderNumber 
> where not exists (select OrderNumber from Orders where InvoiceControl.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber)
> ```

2. Selects a specific Order number that does not exist

> ```
> select OrderNumber from Orders where OrderNumber = 987654
> ```

3. Selects the specific Order Number in the corresponding table that does not exist

> ```
> select OrderNumber from InvoiceControl where OrderNumber = 987654
> ```

these 3 queries work in other scenarios regarding other tables but not this one, have I made an obvious mistake anywhere? below is the query ran and the outputs:
[image]

the idea behind this is to locate the OrderNumbers that do not exist in the InvoiceControl, based on the OrderNumbers in the Orders Tabl, so the top query would also return the value 987654 as this value has not yet been included in the InvoiceControl Table as this could be a new Order without an Invoice

Comment: The query doesn't quite make sense.  You're asking for every ordernumber that appears in the InvoiceControl table that doesn't exist in the InvoiceControl table...  What are you actually trying to get as a result?

Comment: it exists in Orders but not in Invoice Control, and you're using `INNER JOIN`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `INNER JOIN` will already create all correspondents between `Orders.OrderNumber = InvoiceControl.OrderNumber`.

After this result set is built, you actually filter out everything based on the condition in your `WHERE`.

`where not exists (select OrderNumber from Orders where InvoiceControl.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber)`

Hypothetically, if you'd have just `987654` in your `Orders` table and you'd have a Correspondent in your `InvoiceControl` table, then the following query, without your `WHERE` clause

```
select Orders.OrderNumber 
FROM Orders 
inner join InvoiceControl on Orders.OrderNumber = InvoiceControl.OrderNumber
```

would return:

```
OrderNumber
987654
```

Then, by applying your `where not exists (select OrderNumber from Orders where InvoiceControl.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber)` condition, you'd be looking for all records that do not have a correspondent (but you already have all possible correspondents between your two tables, based on your INNER JOIN).

Thus, your result will be:

`OrderNumber`

Comment: cheers, knew it would be something as obvious as that, better check my other Procedures now. thanks pal, a simple LEFT JOIN solved it

Comment: @Crezzer7 Don't forget that depending on what conditions you use in your `WHERE` clause, you might still filter out records, even if you used a **LEFT JOIN**. I think you could simplify your `WHERE` condition by using `WHERE InvoiceControl.OrderNumber IS NULL` instead of your current condition. It has the same functionality/logic, only that it's a little bit faster (because you don't have to run a `SELECT` statement to filter the records out, as you already have the final result set built).

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, you first asked for rows in both Orders and InvoiceControl (by way of the FROM and JOIN tables), and then you added in your WHERE clause a request to exclude all rows that exist in Orders. Since your starting set only includes rows that are in Orders, if you ask for all of those rows to be excluded, you will get no results back.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is to find all the ordernumbers in  tbl Orders and not in tbl InvoiceControl.
Then I would try this instead.

```
Select O.Ordernumbers from Orders O
Left Join Invoicecontrol I
On O.Ordernumbers = I.Ordernumbers
Where I.Ordernumbers is null
```